# asp.net mvc security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, geneva-framework

How can I disallow anonymous access to my ASP.NET mvc controllers?  Specifically,
I want to require authenticated access to all controllers but allow anonymous access
to resource type files such as .css and .js files.   Don't plan on using membership services as I am using Microsoft Geneva.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have your controllers inherit from (your own) ControllerBase.

Add the

[Authorize]

attribute to that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Authorize attribute (action filter) on each action method in each controller if you don't want to sub-class a base controller.

See here for an introduction to action filters: http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-14-cs.aspx